# Use Regex to extract 3 groups of 2 digits

Tags: javascript, html, regex, substring

In javascript i have a var that contains a 13 digit ID number from an HTML form. The 1st 6 digits of this ID number is a date of birth of the format: YYMMDD.

Example input: 9409201234987;
Where 94 is the year, 09 the month, 20 the day.

I need to verify this birthdate, such that:

1. The year is between (inclusive) 1920 - 1997
2. The month is between 1 - 12
3. The day is between 1 - 31

If anyone of these are false my function needs to return false.

This is my function so far:

```js
function validateID(idNum, errors) {
  if (!/^\d{13}$/.test(idNum.value)) {
    errors.innerHTML = "ID Number must be 13 numerical digits";
    return false;
  }
  var year = idNum.value.substring(0, 3);
  var month = idNum.value.substring(3, 5);
  var day = idNum.value.substring(5, 7);

  if (year > 97 || year < 20) {
    errors.innerHTML = "Year is outside of range (1920 - 1997)";
    return false;
  } else if (month > 12 || month < 1) {
    errors.innerHTML = "Month is outside of range (1 - 12)";
    return false;
  } else if (day > 31 || day < 1) {
    errors.innerHTML = "Day is outside of range (1 - 31)";
    return false;
  }
}
```

The parameter: idNum is an HTML form input, type text. And errors is a div in my HTML to output errors to.

Substring obviously isn't working for me, could someone please suggest a different method, using Regex preferably. Thanks!

Comment: You can't compare an int and string with > or < - you need to use parseInt on your year, month and day values

Comment: ....completely forgot about the parseInt function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your substring parameters are wrong. The end parameter is 0-based, not 1-based. Also, you should use `parseInt()` to convert the strings to numbers.

```
var year = parseInt(idNum.value.substring(0, 2), 10);
var month = parseInt(idNum.value.substring(2, 4), 10);
var day = parseInt(idNum.value.substring(4, 6), 10);
```

You could also extract them when you're doing the regexp match.

```
if (!(match = /^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})\d{7}$/.test(idNum.value)) {
    errors.innerHTML = "ID Number must be 13 numerical digits";
    return false;
}
var year = parseInt(match[1], 10);
var month = parseInt(match[2], 10);
var day = parseInt(match[3], 10);
```

Comment: awesome, forgot about the parseInt function... and that's the syntax for the Regex I was looking for, but your substring solution is simpler.